Некорректный вид сайта в Internet Explorer
В Explorer футер поднимается к веру и закрывает часть контента, на отдельный страницах центральный блок растягивается и выглядит некорректно. В других браузерах все выглядит, как нужно. Валидатор ошибок не находит. HTML:1)body 2) header 3)main 4) Footer.SCC:
body {
  background: url(img/fon10.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%;
  }
html {
  min-height: 100%;
.main {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 550px;/*отступ полжен быть больше футера, чтобы не закрывал контент*/
}
footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color:#2E1114;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 2rem 5%;


Какая версия explorer? Хотя, какая разница, его поддержка уже давно не осуществляется Microsoft'ом. Вы уверены, что вам надо верстку для старинного браузера делать?

ИЕ умер до рождения флексов (если мне не изменяет память).

Сайт для оборудования, которое на производствах используют. Есть опасения, что там на заводах, может быть установлен древний браузер. У нас в бухгалтерии именно он, т.к. налоговые порталы через него работают. Надеюсь, что шанс есть и под него адаптировать. Спасибо.

Ну тогда как минимум приведите [mcve], а не невнятный огрызок стилей

@SeVlad, флексы поддерживаются в IE10+ почти без проблем. И даже альтернативная спецификация гридов.

Если действительно нужно "для завода", то не нужно использовать НИКАКИЕ новые технологии. Поехавшая вёртска - это могут быть ещё цветочки. Куда более серьёзные проблемы может доставить функционал, но вы об этом можете и не узнать.


height: 100%;


Это в приведённом коде не работает.

html {
  min-height: 100%;
.main {


Фигурную скобку закрывать кто будет?

padding-bottom: 550px;/отступ полжен быть больше футера, чтобы не закрывал контент/


Какой box-sizing?
IE не умеет флекс-элементы с border-box.
Нафига вообще так делать, если у тебя флекс??


footer {
  position: relative;


Снова фигня. Судя по остальному коду должно быть absolute.

Вот так должно работать, впрочем, в IE сейчас не проверял. Если речь об IE10, то надо добавить префиксы.


html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body > * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer {
  min-height: 60px;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: silver;
}

main {
  padding: 1em;
}
<div class="main">
  <main>Main</main>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>




Спасибо всем неравнодушным, кто откликнулся. Не буду утомлять долгим объяснением, почему я экономист,, сайтом занимаюсь Скажу одно-это очень важно для меня. Не буду притворяться, что все сказанное поняла с полуслова . Прошу понять и простить мне мое невежество. футер с absolut поднимается во всех браузерах, а с  relative только IE. если можно напишу полный код страницы, обновив вопрос В IE нижняя часть div растягивается, на нее заходить футер, карточки сползают вниз и заходят на футер. Валидетор ошибок не видит .

Как только я добавляю свойство html, body {
height: 100%; Все проблемы, которые были в IE появляются и в других браузерах. Если min-height, то все хорошо везде, кроме  IE. Такое чувство, что он сам приписывает это свойство HTML. Что можно сделать?

@maya, во-первых, doctype не забывай. Во-вторых, в ответе есть код, который ясно работает в хроме. Ты явно делаешь как-то не так.

В хроме и др. браузерах все у меня работает. Вопросы только в IE Код из ответа я попробовала и как только добавила html, body {
height: 100%; Все поплыло, также, как в IE. Судя по виду в IE,  он будто сам это свойство применяет.
}

@maya, это не единственное отличие моего кода от твоего. И про doctype я уже сказал.

я попробовала этот код. И у меня все приняло такой же некорректный вид, как и в  IE  doctype есть у меня в НTML везде. Или нужен еще и в Css? Спасибо, что пытаетесь помочь

@maya, когда в сниппете запускаешь, вид корректный или нет?

я исправила высоту центрального div с % на пиксели. Он перестал растягиваться и все стало хорошо и в IE. Но фиксированная ширина плохо выглядит в мобильном приложении. Можно ли ее только для  IE каким-то образом оставить? Или как-то в медиа написать, чтобы в мобильном снова на проценты переходило?

сниппет - пока не знаю, что это за зверь такой. Я сайт еще не разместила на хостинге. IE у меня на удаленном рабочем сервере есть( там бух-я через него работает) Туда папку с сайтом закидываю и смотрю, что вышло. Дома Хром у меня.
